# Ruby pdf testing in browser

Tags: ruby, testing, pdf, webdriver, watir

Has anyone been able to find a way to test pdf's with ruby within the browser?  I have tried a few different ways and the only way I have been able to get any pdf testing to work is to save off the pdf and use the pdf_reader gem.  This only seems to work on pdf's that, when the link is clicked, opens up a dialog box with the options to open or save the pdf.  Unfortunately I have not been able to find a way to do anything like this with pdf's that are opened in browser, with no dialog box options to save it.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to test the PDF in a the browser? Would downloading the PDF work?

Comment: @JustinKo It would technically work, but sometimes there is no option to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe testing it in the browser isnt the best way. When you say test the pdf what are you trying to do? I wouldnt test the pdf in the browser if I was you.

Try [docsplit](http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/), if you want to verify its contents.
`Docsplit is a command-line utility and Ruby library for splitting apart documents into their component parts: searchable UTF-8 plain text via OCR if necessary, page images or thumbnails in any format, PDFs, single pages, and document metadata (title, author, number of pages...)`

Comment: The thing is that it is for site automation, so we have to ensure that the pdf gets created and displayed correctly in a browser(you can technically get different results testing how a pdf is generated dynamically through the web or off of the web).  So to do a true test, it must be done through the web.  Which is unfortunate due to the added complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You are not inventing a browser, or a PDF generator.

Use unit tests to check your back-end modules can take data in, and write PDF out, then serve the PDF in a website and let the browser do its thing. Test (as what Rails calls a "functional test") that the MVC will produce a web page containing a link to the PDF, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem 'mechanize' to download an online PDF (the PDF with in a browser) on your computer and then read it via gem PDF reader.